# FileNotFoundException thrown when changing Maven build directory

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build

I have an IntelliJ Idea Maven project which built successfully up to recently to a `<directory>` specified within the `<build>` of pom file. Given below is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mservice</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mservice Jersey Webapp</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <directory>C:/MService</directory>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- slf4j-log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey-version>1.8</jersey-version>
        <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>m2.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>m2.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>  
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Project is located within D:/Projects/MService.
But since recently, compilation fails with FileNotFoundException and this message.

> Information:Internal caches are corrupted or have outdated format,
>   forcing project  rebuild: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   D:\Projects\MService\C:\MService\classes\com\example\mservice\data\data.txt
>   (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

As given in the message a path confusion happens somewhere and I can't figure it out. If I remove the `<directory>` within `<build>` everything works fine.

`com.example.mservice.data` is a package within the resources folder. All my google searches have been in vain. Is this a problem with IntelliJ or is it a problem with my pom.xml? Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Where exactly is your pom file location and the location of the data.txt file ? Also whether this txt file is required ?

Comment: Why are you changing the `<directory>` ?

Comment: @robin data.txt file is located under resources/com/example/mservice/data directory. Yes, I currently need this txt file for development purposes.

Comment: @khmarbaise My project is a java web application. I test the application with different application containers and settings so I like to keep both the application container and the builds under the same folder

Comment: You should always build to the standard maven `target` directory. Use something to copy your deployable resources to the final destination for testing, perhaps during the `pre-integration-test` phase. Changing the build directory, as you suggest, is non-standard and will lead you into trouble. If you follow standard practice, everything should work fine and you will be more productive.